# Comparison of two Fourier transforms

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am looking for $\delta>0$, such that

$$
\delta \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(its)
{ \Gamma\{2(it+1)/3\}\over \Gamma\{(it+1)/2\} }dt \le \\
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(its)
{ \Gamma (it+1)\over \Gamma\{(it+1)/2\} }dt
$$
for any $s>0$.

Ideally I want to find $\delta(\beta)$ such that
$$
\delta(\beta_1) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(its)
{ \Gamma\{(it+1)/\beta_1\}\over \Gamma\{(it+1)/2\} }dt \le \\
\delta(\beta_2) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(its)
{ \Gamma \{(it+1)/\beta_2\}\over \Gamma\{(it+1)/2\} }dt
$$
for any $s>0$, $1<\beta_2<\beta_1<2$. However it is far more complicated problem. Any hints will be greatly appreciated